# How to mutate props in Vue3 and have the parent computed setter called

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I know this is an anti pattern, but it would simplify things a lot. And furthermore I'm just curious if it's possible. When I call `test1()` I get the following warning: `Set operation on key "items" failed: target is readonly.` and nothing else happens. When I call `test2()` `items` change within the child AND the parent, BUT the computed setter ist not called. Why?

Why is the computed setter not called? Is it possible to mutate the props within the child and still have the computed setter called?

I've got the following parent component:

```
<template>
  <div class="m-10 bg-white">
    parent: {{ items }}
    <br />
    <br />
    <TestComponent2 :items="items" />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { computed, ref } from "vue";
import TestComponent2 from "./TestComponent2.vue";

const container = ref({
  items: ["a", "b", "c"],
});

const items = computed({
  get: () => {
    return container.value.items;
  },
  set: (v) => {
    console.log("set", v);
    container.value.items = v;
  },
});
</script>
```

And this is the child component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    child: {{ items }}
    <br />
    <br />
    <button @click="test1()">test1</button>
    <br />
    <button @click="test2()">test2</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { defineProps, toRefs } from "vue";

const props = defineProps({
  items: {
    type: Array,
    required: true,
  },
});

const { items } = toRefs(props);

const test1 = () => {
  items.value = [];
};

const test2 = () => {
  items.value.pop();
};
</script>
```

Comment: `computed` setter is not a watcher. Setter is called only when the `value` of `ComputedRef<>` is changed. You are not changing it's value, you are mutating the object the value refers to

Comment: That's a good point. Which means that a watcher in the parent component is able to detect changes via pop, splice, etc.. Right? And the watcher could then mutate the values in the parent component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're likely looking for `v-model:items="items"`.

The gist:

**parent.vue:**

```
<child v-model:items="items" />
```

**child.vue:**

```
emit('update:items', value);
```

*Note:* both `items.pop()` and `items.push()` will mutate the value in both parent and child, but they won't trigger an assignment.

For that, you have to:

```
const copy = [...items];
copy.push('new'); // or pop(), splice()...
// if inside child:
emit('update:items', copy);
```

---

Docs [here](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#usage-with-v-model)

Working example [here](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

---

Technically,

```
<child v-model:items="items" />
```

is shorthand for:

```
<child
  :items="items"
  @update:items="value => items = value"
/>
```

In you don't specify the child variable name (in our case `items`), it defaults to `modelValue`.

Comment: Thanks, that's how I'm doing it a the moment. I'm mainly wondering if there's another way. watch looks quite promising, because it seems like there is no way to reassign props but it's fine to call methods like splice on them.

Comment: @danielmoessner, you can always watch deep and compare, but at that point you might as well start asking yourself why you're using Vue in the first-place, you're dispensing with its benefits. The link got too long to post in a comment, so I made a fiddle to share it: https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/6ydc2Lqg/

Comment: Thanks, why would you not do it like this? Because it works and doesn't seem to be too ugly? Isn't it opinionated to prohibit props from being mutated, there are many cases in which it would make sense, isn't there?

Comment: @daniel, it's not opinionated at all. It's how Vue is built: props down, events up. If you mutate props in children, when the value updates in parent your mutation is lost (overwritten). And if the parent would watch for mutations from children it would be considerably slower. You don't have to like it, but if you want to use Vue, it's very useful to know this, as it will likely save you hours of useless debugging.

Comment: The speed is an interesting argument.